# How to use ListTileTheme to style ListTile inside ListView?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use ListTileStyle after ListView

```
ListView(
  ListTileStyle(),
  Children:<widget>[
    ListTile(),
    ListTile(),
    ListTile(),
  ]
),
```

but not able to use any property of ListTile.
Can any one explain how ListTileStyle works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use "ListTileTheme" instead with your ListView as a child, so you can change any property of all the ListTiles you're going to use as childs.

```
ListTileTheme(
        //properties you want to add
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[//your code],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: as far as I can tell, there is no way to add this to the theme at the moment so here is the link for those who want to track the progress https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31247

Comment: Flutter now includes `listTileTheme` in the `ThemeData` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTileThemeData-class.html

Answer (score 1):

```dart
ListView(
  Children:<widget>[
    ListTile(),
    ListTile(),
    ListTileTheme(
      //do sth.
      child:  ListTile(
      ),
    )
  ]
),
```

Comment: Hi, please be more expansive in your answer than by just posting code. The original question was about explanation, so please try to provide one

Answer (score 1):

Flutter now has the field [`listTileTheme`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTileThemeData-class.html) in [`ThemeData`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html),
so if you want to share the same list tile theme across your app, you can set it in the theme you provide to the `MaterialApp`:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    listTileTheme: ListTileThemeData(
      // The properties you want to set.
    ),
  ),
  home: // Your home screen.
);
```